# Matlab) size func (Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals)

Tags: matlab, size, subscript

I want to make function, outputs a mean-value of a input image's partial window.

so , I implemented the simple function, in matlab

`

```
[m] = function compute_mean ( Input, r,w, size )
% r,w is coordinate of window's central point.
a = size(Input);
b=size(a);
if(b(2) ==3 )
    Input = rgb2gray(Input);
end
row = a(1); col = a(2);
......
```

`
It has no warnings.

But It causes error. in line 2. ( a = size(Input) )
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

I don't know why this error appers.

give me a solution, this case, please.

Answer (score 0):

Your 4th input argument, which is size, has the same name of the size function of Matlab. change the size to for example sz. then your code would become some thing like:

```
[m] = function compute_mean ( Input, r,w, sz)
% r,w is coordinate of window's central point.
a = size(Input);
b=size(a);
if(b(2) ==3 )
    Input = rgb2gray(Input);
end
row = a(1); col = a(2);
......
```

Before choosing a name for a function or variable or an argument, always check weather it is a MATLAB internal function name or not. Otherwise, MATLAB will consider the last notation that was defined by you.